# Templated overloaded operator is ambiguous

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, operator-overloading

I have a container `template <typename T> class A` whose `operator+` needs to be overloaded for many other containers, for expression templates and for literal types `U`.

My current strategy is to define a template function `wrap` that encapsulates how individual elements are accessed and define

```cpp
template <typename T, typename U>
auto operator+(Wrapped<T>&& lhs, Wrapped<U>&& rhs) -> decltype(...)
{
    ....
}
```

The following overloaded `operator+`, however, is ambiguous:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename U>
auto operator+(const A<T>& lhs, U&& rhs) ->
    decltype(wrap(lhs) + wrap(std::forward<U>(rhs)))
{
    return wrap(lhs) + wrap(std::forward<U>(rhs));
}

template <typename T, typename U>
auto operator+(T&& lhs, const A<U>& rhs) ->
    decltype(wrap(std::forward<T>(lhs)) + wrap(rhs))
{
    return wrap(std::forward<T>(lhs)) + wrap(rhs);
}
```

How can I resolve the ambiguity best?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide an overload template that's better than both on the arguments it's ambiguous for:

```
template<typename T>
auto operator+(const A<T> &lhs, const A<T> &rhs) -> ...;

template<typename T, typename U>
auto operator+(const A<T> &lhs, const A<U> &rhs) -> ...;
```

Comment: I was thinking on the same line. I still get an overload ambiguity, however.

Comment: @jk4736 if you post more code it might be possible to tell how to resolve the ambiguity.  What arguments is the call ambiguous for?

Comment: Oh! Could it be ambiguous because operator+ is called with an rvalue A<T>?

Comment: @jk4736 quite possibly; I assumed you had that overload already.

Comment: Yes, I tested it, the additional overloads resolve the issue. Is there a way to avoid the code duplication?

Comment: I guess I'll use std::enable_if to avoid duplicating code, which is beyond the scope of this question. Thanks for your answer.